# Unity3d: OnCollisionEnter issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have came across similar problem which few people already posted on the forum. I checked the exisiting posts but still not couldn't rectify the issue. I have cube in my program which hits the floor when program starts. However, I found that onCollisionEnter is not being called when cube hits the floor. Rigidbody is attached to the cube. Could anyone guide me where am I making mistake?

[image]

Code of cube is:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3.5f;
    public float jumpingforce = 10f;
    private bool canjump = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0,jumpingforce,0);
        }
    }

    void onCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("checking collision....");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) needs to start (as btw any method and class name should in c#) with a **capital `O`** .. otherwise Unity will not recognize it and never call it. Unity calls these methods (like also `Awake`, `Start`, `Update`) as "Messages". If they do not exactly match the name they are never found and never called.

---

Some more things:

- Do not call `GetComponent` repeatedly. It is quite expensive! Rather store the reference once and re-use it.
- Then whenever a Rigidbody is involved you should **not** update it's transformations using the `Transform` component! This breaks the Physics! Rather use [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) within `FixedUpdate`
- Small Sidenote: Remove any empty Unity message method like `Start`, `Awake`, `Update`. Even if they are empty they are called by Unity as message only causing unnecessary overhead.

So you should change your code to something like

```c#
public class cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3.5f;
    public float jumpingforce = 10f;
    private bool canjump = false;

    // you can also already reference this via the Inspector
    // then it skips the GetComponnet call
    [SerializeField] privte Rigidbody rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>()
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Getting this input in FixedUpdate is ok since it is a continues call
        if(Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            rigidbdy.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            rigidbdy.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // this one-time input event has to be checked in Update / frame-based
        // since it is true only for one frame and FixedUpdate might not be called during that frame
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            // also it's ok calling this in Update since it is a one-time event
            // and unlikely to happen twice until FixedUpdate is called again
            rigidbody.AddForce(0,jumpingforce,0);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("checking collision....");
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice you still wrote onCollisionEnter with small 'o'